# What log files to include when reporting a bug report for my wlan card?

Tags: debian, drivers, wifi, bugs

I'd like to report a bug with my wireless card cutting out (seemingly) randomly, but I don't know what log files to include.

I know a `tail -F` of a particular log file when the card cuts out would be invaluable.

I just don't want to submit a bug report with no log files that will get lost in the shuffle.

Right now, I'd attach the following:

1. `lspci | grep -i ethernet`
2. `lshw -C network`

But I still need some sort of log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally when reporting the bugs the bug reporting system tells you what files to include, but if they don't then:

```
/var/log/dmesg
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/messages
lspci -vvv
```

Possibly

```
/var/log/syslog
```

But you can simply install:

[Debian BTS](http://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting)

and just follow the instructions. :)